# Rotativa Unhandled Execution Error on server but not locally

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rotativa

Rotativa is giving my an error on the server but works well locally.

Here is the trace :

```
[Exception]
   Rotativa.Core.WkhtmltopdfDriver.Convert(DriverOptions options, String html) +766
   Rotativa.MVC.ViewAsPdf.CallTheDriver(ControllerContext context) +1287
   Rotativa.MVC.AsPdfResultBase.BuildPdf(ControllerContext context) +192
   ....GenererPdfImpression(String idFeuilleDeBord) in D:\...\FeuilleDeBordController.cs:239
```

Answer (score 0):

Visual C++ distribuable had been removed from the server.
I just reinstalled it and it worked.